# Get user download apk

Tags: android

Need some help i'm able to retrieving *.apk file name from Android device programmaticaly . Could any body provide to get only user downloaded apk file . please help

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Could any body provide to get only user downloaded apk file . please
>   help

So i think there is not trivial solution. But what whe know:

- Each .apk file's name is in a form `<packageName>[some optional text].apk`

So solution came to my head now is that you need to loop through installed applications (ApplicationInfo) and then test each package with name of current .apk file:

```
if (file.getName().contains(packageInfo.packageName)) {
   // its User downloaded .apk file
}
```

To filter only non-system applications (packages) you can use this condition:

```
if ((info.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) == 0) {
   // non-system application
}
```

So finally it can looks like (pseudo-code):

```
for (File f: apkFiles) {

   String name = f.getName();

   for (ApplicationInfo info: packageManager.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA) {

      if ((info.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) == 0) {

          if (name.contains(info.packageName)) {
             // it's User downloaded .apk file

             break;
          } 

      }
   }
}
```

### Note:

But there is problem if downloaded .apk file is not installed. I think if you want to differentiate .apk files (user downloaded and not) i think that only one solution (which is not reliable) is to get when file was created and all files which date is after date when was installed OS should be user downloaded.

Comment: @HarshitRathi welcome mate. So if it works can you accept this one? Thanks